# Fajr Starting Sunrise vs Sunrise Full

Tags: fajr

I have confusion regarding what is sunrise as in Fajr ending
Bcz sun stars to rise is that to be considered or when it risen fully

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.

Fajr ends when it's sunrise. Nowadays, Islamic apps and even weather apps tell you when sunrise is, all you have to do is pray before you get notified.

Answer (score 1):

Sunrise means when the disk of the sun starts to be visible at the horizon. That is the time Fajr ends. It doesn't need to completely be over the horizon.